# Plotly express animation: changes in hoverlabel only applied for the first frame

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'continent': {127: 'South America',
  128: 'South America',
  129: 'South America',
  130: 'South America',
  131: 'South America'},
 'date': {127: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  128: Timestamp('2021-03-26 00:00:00'),
  129: Timestamp('2021-04-20 00:00:00'),
  130: Timestamp('2021-05-15 00:00:00'),
  131: Timestamp('2021-06-09 00:00:00')},
 'total_cases': {127: 20465329.0,
  128: 23470911.0,
  129: 26544779.0,
  130: 29891133.0,
  131: 30534015.0}})

fig = px.bar(df, x='continent', y='total_cases', animation_frame=df.date.astype(str),
#              hover_data={'animation_frame':False,
#                         'continent':False,
#                         }
            )

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='Date:%{animation_frame}<br>Total Cases:%{y}')
```

Running the above code outputs a barchart with an animation slider. The changes made to the hoverlabel are visible only as long as you dont move the slider. Once you do that and the frame changes, the default `plotly.express` hoverlabel reappears (I think because the trace updates). Is there any fix to this?

**Edit:** Adding a GIF to show the issue

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2722), and as of writing the only solution seems to be to add the following to your setup:

```
for f in fig.frames:
    f.data[0].update(hovertemplate='Date:%{animation_frame}<br>Total Cases:%{y}')
```

[image]

You'll also need to keep:

```
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='Date:%{animation_frame}<br>Total Cases:%{y}')
```

If you don't, then the first frame *before* you run any animation by pressing `play` or moving the slider back and forth will still display this:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'continent': {127: 'South America',
  128: 'South America',
  129: 'South America',
  130: 'South America',
  131: 'South America'},
 'date': {127: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  128: Timestamp('2021-03-26 00:00:00'),
  129: Timestamp('2021-04-20 00:00:00'),
  130: Timestamp('2021-05-15 00:00:00'),
  131: Timestamp('2021-06-09 00:00:00')},
 'total_cases': {127: 20465329.0,
  128: 23470911.0,
  129: 26544779.0,
  130: 29891133.0,
  131: 30534015.0}})

fig = px.bar(df, x='continent', y='total_cases', animation_frame=df.date.astype(str),
#              hover_data={'animation_frame':False,
#                         'continent':False,
#                         }
            )

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='Date:%{animation_frame}<br>Total Cases:%{y}')
for f in fig.frames:
    f.data[0].update(hovertemplate='Date:%{animation_frame}<br>Total Cases:%{y}')

fig.show()
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Nice to have fine tuned controls for each frame.

Comment: @callmeanythingyouwant Glad to hear it! Happy to help!